# Syncing up two git remote repositories

Tags: git, gitlab

One repository sits on a network share and another is hosted in GitLab. The problem is that the server that hosts the GitLab instance does not see the network share.
Some people push to the GitLab, some people push to the network share, and some push some stuff to one and some to the other.

Keeping the two repos up to date is getting extremely difficult.

I would occasionally take my working copy of the dev branch (which is where most commits are done), sync it up with GitLab, put it on a tumb drive and copy it to a machine that can see the share. Then I would replace the GitLab remote it's tracking with the network share remote and sync up, then take it back and sync with the gitlab.

I've ran into problems with that (index errors, etc), so now I rsync the gitlab version to my working directory, then push to the network share. 
That has not gone as smoothly as expected either. The time zones on the machines are different and that seems to be tripping up rsync.

What would be the proper method (other than getting rid of one of the remotes) to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to to this is to not have two remotes in the first place. Since that doesn't seem to be an option, the correct way to do this is to sync them on a local machine that can see both repositories and push the synced state to both repositories:

```
git pull share branch
git push gitlab branch
```

To be more effective at this you may be interested in fetching from the remote and comparing the different remotes to merge the states easier